# Is there a difference between GLSL/GLM and Python/numpy when it comes to 4x4 matrix multiplication?

Tags: python, glsl, pyopengl

Basically, this works:

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(self.shader.program, "projection"), 1, GL_FALSE, self.P)
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(self.shader.program, "view"), 1, GL_FALSE, self.V)
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(self.shader.program, "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, self.M)
```

```
#version 330 core

layout (location=0) in vec3 vertexPos;
layout (location=1) in vec2 vertexTexCoord;
layout (location=2) in vec3 vertexNormal;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

out vec2 fragmentTexCoord;

void main(){
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(vertexPos, 1.0);
    fragmentTexCoord = vertexTexCoord;
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
self.PVM = np.matmul(self.P, np.matmul(self.V, self.M))
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(self.shader.program, "PVM"), 1, GL_FALSE, self.PVM)
```

```
#version 330 core

layout (location=0) in vec3 vertexPos;
layout (location=1) in vec2 vertexTexCoord;
layout (location=2) in vec3 vertexNormal;

uniform mat4 PVM;

out vec2 fragmentTexCoord;

void main(){
    gl_Position = PVM * vec4(vertexPos, 1.0);
    fragmentTexCoord = vertexTexCoord;
}
```

Passing in each matrix individually then doing the multiplication within the shader produces expected result (i.e. I can see the model and move around, etc.). Calculating the PVM matrix in Python first makes the model disappear. The above code is all I'm changing.

Comment: `self.PVM = np.matmul(self.M, np.matmul(self.V, self.P))`

Comment: @Rabbid76 I've tried using `np.matmul`, `np.dot` and even `pyrr.matrix44.multiply`. All seem to produce the same result.

Comment: Did you try the reverse order linke in my comment?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Ah, thank you very much! I didn't notice you'd swapped the order - all working now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`numpy.matmul`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) behaves different than a GLSL matrix multiplication. Compare [`numpy.matmul`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) and [GLSL Programming/Vector and Matrix Operations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations). You have to reverse the order of the matrix multiplication:

<s>`self.PVM = np.matmul(self.P, np.matmul(self.V, self.M))`</s>

```py
self.PVM = np.matmul(self.M, np.matmul(self.V, self.P))
```